# Getting Error In Android Setting Camera Help Neded

Tags: java, android, xml, camera

i am learning android camera capture and set it to wallpaper from tutorials but getting error i try hard to find but cant figure it out i set this class in another class by anotherlistitem click here is my code.

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView iv;
ImageButton ib;
Button b;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
    initilize();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.BResults:

        break;

    case R.id.ibtakenimage:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("Data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}

public void initilize() {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimageview);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtakenimage);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BResults);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

}

and here is my logcat.

```
    01-14 02:37:21.770: E/Trace(1247): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-14 02:37:22.200: D/dalvikvm(1247): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 9% free 2442K/2660K, paused 55ms, total 57ms
    01-14 02:37:22.210: I/dalvikvm-heap(1247): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.103MB for 614416-byte allocation
    01-14 02:37:22.250: D/dalvikvm(1247): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3040K/3264K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
    01-14 02:37:22.280: D/dalvikvm(1247): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3190K/3416K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 38ms
    01-14 02:37:22.520: D/gralloc_goldfish(1247): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    01-14 02:37:28.100: I/Choreographer(1247): Skipped 195 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-14 02:37:28.270: I/Choreographer(1247): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-14 02:37:43.140: I/Choreographer(1247): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-14 02:37:43.440: D/AndroidRuntime(1247): Shutting down VM
    01-14 02:37:43.460: W/dalvikvm(1247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
   ----->>>>  01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidme/com.example.androidme.Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at                                android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at com.example.androidme.Camera.initilize(Camera.java:58)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at com.example.androidme.Camera.onCreate(Camera.java:24)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
   01-14 02:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):  ... 11 more
```

----> Error Start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.androidme.Camera.initilize(Camera.java:58)
```

tells you the error. In line 58 of your Camera class, you're trying to access an object that does not exist, i.e. is null.

It must be one of these lines:

```
b.setOnClickListener(this);
ib.setOnClickListener(this);
```

so all you have to do is check whether the IDs you typed in before are correct with the ones you specified in your .xml.